# output colored text in multiple output of function in R

Tags: r, function, text, colors

I am new to writing functions in R. When a function shall create multpile outputs, I aggregate these outputs to a list and make the function return this list. This method also allows for the output of simple text. However, I seem not to be able to print colored text.

An example:

```
library (crayon)

my_function <- function (a = 3, b = 6) {
    first_result <- a * 3
    second_result <- b / a
    print (list (first_result, 
                 second_result, 
                 "my_text"))
}

my_function()
```

which puts out (and is ok for me):

```
[[1]]
[1] 9

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] "my_text"
```

Now I want to see "my_text" in color (which works):

```
cat (green ("my_text"))
```

However, when put in a list, the behaviour is not my desired one - the text is put out first, the first argument in the list follows up:

```
x <- 5
list (x, cat (green ("my_text")))
```

compare to:

```
list (x, "my_text")
```

This behaviour is a bit unlucky for me - I want the function to put out a colored line of text after the results. My attempt

```
my_function <- function (a = 3, b = 6) {
    first_result <- a * 3
    second_result <- b / a
    print (list (first_result, 
                 second_result, 
                 cat (green ("my_text"))))
}

my_function()
```

of course did not work out. Unfortunately, I have no alternative idea on printing colored text in R. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `cat()` is built to output results to the console, it returns a value of `NULL`. So as R is interpreting your `list()` call it sees `cat()` and immediately does its thing and outputs "my text" to the console and then stashes the `NULL` as the third element. Is "my text" a relevant part of the results or is it more of an alert the user?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. "My Text" is not really a relevant part of the result. My aim was to use colored text as titles of the different results of the function (I know that storing these 'titles' as individual objects in a list is not the most elegant approach - due to my limited knowledge of programming I simply had no other idea...)

Answer (score 1):

Cat does not return a variable, and instead returns `NULL`.

Does the green output need to be in the list? If not then this can work:

```
my_function <- function (a = 3, b = 6) {
first_result <- a * 3
second_result <- b / a
print (list (first_result, 
           second_result 
           ))
cat(green ("my_text"))
}

my_function()
```

I tried using capture.output(), but it only captures the text and not the colour.

```
print(capture.output(cat(green ("my_text"))))
```

I also tried using R markdown (https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/index.html) and also then you lose the coloration. So I don't believe it is currently possible

Comment: Of course, this works fine. However, when storing the results of the function in an object, the colored text will be ommited when I call the respective object. Ideally, this should not be happening.